# C# ASP.NET equivalent of Classic ASP Server.CreateObject().Exists()

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I've been tasked with converting a Classic ASP application into an ASP.NET MVC5 application, however I'm a bit stuck with finding the equivalent of `Server.CreateObject().Exists()` for C# ASP.NET.

Classic ASP:

```
Set courseDirectory = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

If Not (courseDirectory.Exists(clashKey)) AND Not (courseDirectory.Exists(altClashKey)) Then
    '...
End If
```

C# equivalent so far:

```
object courseDirectory = new object();

courseDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary");

//problem here
if (!(courseDirectory.Exists())...
```

What do I have to do in order to achieve the same thing in C# ASP.NET?

Comment: Try declaring `courseDirectory` as `dynamic`. This will allow you to call the COM methods through a dynamic wrapper which will marshall the calls correctly. See "COM Interop" in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: @RB. Interesting. I'll see how that goes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. In theory you can just translate code from asp to c# and it will work - but you were tasked with converting the code to ASP.NET MVC5, and there are ways to do things. I am not sure I would go with Server.CreateObject. besides, what error are you getting.

Comment: @gilmishal I'm not getting any compilation/build errors, but the `Exists()` method doesn't exist for `HttpContext.Current.Server.CreateObject()`. In other words, Intellisense gives an error when I try to call that method.

Comment: you are not "converting" anything. you are just porting your vbscript codebase to .net which is really bad. there are no benefits in just using the same com objects in .net as you did in vbscipt. if you want any benefits of using .net you have to rewrite your application in .net

Comment: @ulluoink It's only this part that needs porting. I've converted everything else thus far to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a normal dictionary? How about:

```
var courseDirectory = new Dictionary<string, object>()
```